# extracting Byte by Byte from an ArrayOfByte

Tags: java, android

i have an ArrayOfByte like this:

```
byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024]
```

It contains array of 1,2,3,4 inside it randomly..

Assume there are about 100 Byte data in it,

my question is how to extract byte by byte data from it :
it i use `Log.d(TAG, "arrayOfByte :"+arrayOfByte);` it will display `arrayOfByte :[B@2b052c60`

now i want to extract each byte separately and `display: 1,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,4,4,4,2,3,3,3...` like this

**UPDATE:**
Thanks Sumit Singh, it worked ..

now suppose we `display: [1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

**Question1:** how to put these values in some `int[] series`

**Question2:** can i delete few starting elements from it and make it `[2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Arrays.toString(byte[] a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29):

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as by `String.valueOf(byte)`. Returns "null" if a is null.

```
Arrays.toString(arrayOfByte)
```

It will return String representation of your byte array like `1,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,4,4,4,2,3,3,3` So

```
Log.d(TAG, "arrayOfByte :"+ Arrays.toString(arrayOfByte));
```

**Updated for next Questions**

**Ans 1:**

- There are many ways to do this simplest is iterate over each byte array element and widening primitives from char to int: [JLS 5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.2)
- You can use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which is part of **NIO** like following:

  `int[] intArray = ByteBuffer.wrap(arrayOfByte).asIntBuffer().array()`

**Ans 2:**

For this question also there are lots of way, one i'm suggesting is use [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). It will return new array with your given range.

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array. The initial index of the range (from) must lie between zero and original.length, inclusive. The value at original[from] is placed into the initial element of the copy (unless from == original.length or from == to). Values from subsequent elements in the original array are placed into subsequent elements in the copy. The final index of the range (to), which must be greater than or equal to from, may be greater than original.length, in which case (byte)0 is placed in all elements of the copy whose index is greater than or equal to original.length - from. The length of the returned array will be to - from.

```
byte[] newByteArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayOfByte, startIndex, endIndex);
```